# Should I include the managed object context as a parameter to a method?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, methods, coding-style

**Problem**

I'm including the managed object context as a parameter of a method when I work with Core Data.

Although this makes the code easier to test, it's messy.

**Questions**

- Is this good or bad practice?
- Is there a neater, easier way of doing this that keeps methods testable?

**Background**

The example below is a background operation that has it's own context.

Any advice from more experienced coders would be much appreciated!

**Code**

```
@interface JGTrainingGroupCleanupOperation : JGCoreDataOperation {
    NSManagedObjectContext  *imoc;
}

...

@implementation JGTrainingGroupCleanupOperation

-(void)main {
    [self startOperation];                    // Setting up the local context etc
    [self cleanupTrainingGroupsInMOC:imoc];   
    [self finishOperation];
}

-(void)cleanupTrainingGroupsInMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc {
    NSSet *trainedGroups = [self fetchAllTrainedGroupsInMOC:moc];

    [self deleteDescendantsOfGroups:trainedGroups fromMOC:moc];
    [self removeStubAncestorsOfGroups:trainedGroups fromMOC:moc];    
}

-(NSSet *)fetchAllTrainedGroupsInMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc_ {
    return [moc_ fetchObjectsForEntityName:kTrainingGroup withPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"projectEditedAtTopLevel == nil"]];
}

-(void)deleteDescendantsOfGroups:(NSSet *)trainedGroups fromMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc_ {
    // More code here
}

-(void)deleteDescendantsOfGroup:(JGTrainingGroup *)trainedGroup fromMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc_ {
    // More code here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my (not so humble) opinion I'd say it's mostly a matter of style. You can do it this way or you can `@synthesize` the moc and call `[self moc]` or `self.moc`.

Me? I'd go the accessor route personally, mostly because class members shouldn't have to be told where to find an object dereferenced by an iVar anyway. If you're accessing something that's an iVar within the same class, I'd use the iVar directly or an accessor.

I *believe* the difference in performance would be negligible, so I wouldn't really bother much on that front (even though you didn't ask).

Comment: As with all good answers, it seems so obvious with hindsight. Of course that's the way to do it. Can't believe I didn't think of this. Thanks so much for the help!